# Create a git command to open repository in browser

Tags: git, git-alias

I want to create a `git alias` which will allow me to do `git visit` and the repository will be opened in the browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me in Git for Windows with Git Bash.  Place the following in your git configuration file:

```
[alias]
visit      = "!git remote get-url origin | xargs -r start"
visitfancy = "!f() { REMOTE=${1:-origin}; URL=$(git remote get-url \"$REMOTE\"); if [[ -n \"$URL\" ]]; then start \"$URL\"; fi; }; f"
```

`visit` will just launch the remote url of `origin` if it exists.

`visitfancy` will launch the remote url of the remote name you specify, or default to `origin` if none is specified.

Answer (score 4):

When you type a command such as `git xyz`, git looks for a file named `git-xyz` and if found, it executes it. You can simulate such behavior by putting a file named `git-visit` in a directory which is in the `PATH`, and then `git visit` will execute it.

The content of the file should be

```sh
xdg-open $(git remote -v | cut -d @ -f 2 | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | head -1 | sed 's/:/\//' | sed 's/.git$//' | sed s'/^/https:\/\//') >& /dev/null &
```

(`xdg-open` might not work on your machine).

**Note that you must do `chmod +x git-xyz` in order to make the file executable**

Answer (score 1):

If this repo has a GitHub remote, you can say `hub browse` (if you have installed [`hub`](https://hub.github.com)).

Answer (score 1):

There is a tiny and handy tool for this purpose. You can easy install it via npm and different commands to open your repo in the browser.

```
- npm install --global git-open
- git open
```

[Here](https://github.com/paulirish/git-open) you can find the documentation for other useful commands

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following:

```
[alias]
        visit = "!f(){ xdg-open `git config --get remote.origin.url | sed -Ee 's#(git@|git://)#https://#' -e 's@com:@com/@'`| head -n1; }; f"
```

It works for SSH and HTTPS cloned repository + GitHub and GitLab

Answer (score 0):

##### what I use on osx:

Use the desired browser by simply replacing **`Firefox.app`** with eg. `Safari.app`, `Brave Browser.app`, `Google Chrome.app` ...

```
alias visit='open -a "/Applications/Firefox.app" $(git config --get remote.origin.url)'
```

Answer (score 0):

On windows you can run the following command in your repo terminal:

```
start (git config --get remote.origin.url)
```